# True meaning of memory exhaustion error?

Tags: php

I recently got this pretty standard looking error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 343982 bytes)

Except it says it cannot allocate 0.34 MB out of 134MB.

All the answers from Google point to adding more memory to the script, however, I do not see why I need to add more memory to a script that already has 394x it's memory requirements.

How is this possible?

For details sake I run:

- PHP 5.5
- Nginx 1.6
- Ubuntu 14.01

Comment: Could you improve the way the memory is handled in the PHP code itself?

Comment: @craig1231 not sure if it is only allocating 0.34mb, I am checking it now but it is a confusing error, not sure if I know why it is happening even if I found the reason

Comment: @Sammaye The error says that you've already allocated almost 134MB, and the last allocation (of 0.34 MB) crossed the threshold of the max total of 134MB.

Comment: @Sammaye No, its saying at the point of exhaustion, which is 128MB it tried to allocate a further 0.33MB. But it cant because it has already reached its limit of 128MB

Comment: Ah I get it now, it is trying to allocate another 0.34mb and cannot, ok kool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point of exhaustion, which is 128MB it tried to allocate a further 0.33MB. But it cant because it has already reached its limit of 128MB.